# What event is fired when a UserControl is displayed?

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to add a fade effect (animation) for WPF `UserControls` (although rather for `FrameworkElement`, to make it more general).

If I let the `Loaded` event trigger the initial fade-in, the fade animation will sometimes have started before the UserControl has been displayed. The result is a mess. That happens for example if the UserControl does something lengthy (a few tenths of a second), like execute a query, in the Loaded event handler.

So, I would need to handle some event that FrameworkElement/UserControl gets when the content has been rendered, and start the fade-in then. The `System.Windows.Window` has a `ContentRendered` event, but UserControl has not. So, what event is fired when a FrameworkElement (or UserControl) has been rendered?

Comment: I can't give an anser - because of my Reputation, but I need to extend this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708039/what-event-is-fired-when-a-usercontrol-is-displayed/18569270#18569270](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708039/what-event-is-fired-when-a-usercontrol-is-displayed/18569270#18569270) First of all - this helped me a lot.
To make sure it's rendered completely, add the `IsLoaded` to the if statement

Answer (score 27):

Try to check size on SizeChanged or LayoutUpdated. Do job when actual width or height not equals to 0.

```
view.LayoutUpdated+=(o,e)=>
{
  if (!loaded && (view.ActualHeight > 0 || view.ActualWidth > 0))
  {
     // You can also unsubscribe event here.
     loaded =true;
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. IsVisibleChanged did not work. Have my upvote

Answer (score 19):

Years late, but since I was looking for working solution since now in vain, I want to share my discovery.

If you want a `ContentRendered` event for any Control (or any Visual or even DependencyObject), you have to dig down to `Visual`.

I use this code:

```
// Wait for Control to Load
void TestUserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get PresentationSource
    PresentationSource presentationSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual((Visual)sender);

    // Subscribe to PresentationSource's ContentRendered event
    presentationSource.ContentRendered += TestUserControl_ContentRendered;
}

void TestUserControl_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Don't forget to unsubscribe from the event
    ((PresentationSource)sender).ContentRendered -= TestUserControl_ContentRendered;

    // ..
}
```

You have to wait for Control `Loaded` otherwise PresentationSource.FromVisual() returns null.

Various Dispatcher.BeginInvoke methods didn't work consistently for me. Sometimes firing my rendered event long before the control was actually displayed.
This does work for me every time.

I am aware that I am playing with HwndSource here, which is quite low level and I'm not sure of possible implications. (Maybe somebody more experienced can elaborate.)

Comment: Unfortunately, `ContentRendered` fires only the first time the owner `Window` finishes rendering; that means: if this `UserControl` (or whatever `DependencyObject`) is rendered **after** `ContentRendered` is fired, it won't fire again. This issue might be countered when you have some controls that are lazily loaded depending on user interaction.

Answer (score 10):

You can use IsVisibleChnaged event
Assign event handler

```
MyUserControl.IsVisibleChanged += ScheduleUserControl_IsVisibleChanged;
```

In event handler check for if is visible or not.

```
void _IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((bool)e.NewValue)
    {
        //Visible
    }
    else
    {
        //Not Visible
    }
}
```

Comment: nice trick , thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can schedule the beginning of your `Storyboard` with a lower priority, for example:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(BeginStoryboardAction, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
```

Here's an article that discusses the issues related to using this method:

- [Build More Responsive Apps With The Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe try `IsVisibleChanged`, haven't used it much myself though.

> This event is not raised if the element is not being rendered by the layout system, for reasons other than the value of the IsVisible property. For example, the element might not have an associated visual.

Comment: Nope, the element has IsVisible == true already in the Loaded event handler.

Comment: Too bad, how about triggering your fade in manually when your initial work is completed?

Comment: The problem is - where should I trigger it? After the Loaded event is handled, something lengthy still takes place. It's probably WPF databinding that triggers Entity Framework loading from the database somewhere between the Loaded event and the display of the UserControl.

Answer (score 3):

You can use GotFocus Event

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ContentControlLoadedCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```