# Is there any event after Loaded and before showing the user control?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, onload

I'm loading user controls in a specific grid in our application and I'm adding animations to the loading user controls in the `Loaded` event handler of the controls.

Some of the user controls are lightweight and some of them need heavy computations before loading. The problem is that when I add a 1 second animation to the heavy user controls then showing the control so endures that the animation never can be seen!

Is there any other event that I can add my animation to the user control so that the heavy ones and the light ones get displayed with the same animation?

I need an event right before showing the control. `OnLoaded` doesn't seem to be right place for me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was giving the Storyboard.Begin a lower priority.

I found out it from this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4708172/970420

So we have this code for beginning the animation :

```
    void BeginStoryboardAction(Storyboard sb)
    {
        sb.Begin();
    }
```

and we should call it by this way :

```
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<Storyboard>(BeginStoryboardAction), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, sb);
```

**sb** is an instance of Storyboard which has some animations in it.

[Edit] :
Another shorter way :

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<Storyboard>(delegate (Storyboard stb){stb.Begin();}), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, sb);
```

Answer (score 3):

When a window is first opened, the Loaded and ContentRendered events are raised only after the Activated event is raised. With this in mind, a window can effectively be considered opened when ContentRendered is raised.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx

Comment: Thanks Aksel for your attention but I tested ContentRendered for the container window and it just get fired one time at startup and never get fired again. However I get to the solution :) The solution resides here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4708172/970420 as Rick said we should schedule story board begin so that it has the lowest priority. So I added `void BeginStoryboardAction() { sb.Begin(); }` and deferred calling to it by this way : ` Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(BeginStoryboardAction), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);` it works like a charm even for heavy loading user controls :)

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for a generic way to execute code right after components being created but before they are rendered the `LayoutUpdated` event helps. This should work inside of windows as well as  inside of user or custom controls.