# UserControl BringIntoView() not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, scrollbar

***Background:***
I have a `usercontrol` defined in a `ScrollViewer` along with a `ContentControl`, the `ContentControl` will be visible all the time, and within it there is a `Button`, when the button is clicked will set the `usercontrol` to `Visible`, and when the `usercontrol` shows (`Visiblility="Visible"`) I want it to be scrolled into the view. I have

*XAML*

```
<ScrollViewer  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  MaxHeight="465">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyOtherViewModel}"  Width="960" ></ContentControl>
    <local:MyView  IsVisibleChanged="MyView_IsVisibleChanged" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding IsNonCompliant, Converter={StaticResource BooltoVisible}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />        
</ScrollViewer>
```

*Code Behind*

```
private void MyView_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as Control).BringIntoView();        
        }
```

***Problem:*** this is not working, or more precisely, my `usercontrol` scrolled into the view first then revert back to the bottom of the `ScrollViewer` in a blink.

***Weird thing:*** show a `messagebox` before calling `BringIntoView` will correctly display my `usercontrol` into the middle of the view

***Current hack solution:*** you can see this works even to close the `Window` immediately after its `loaded`

```
private void MyView_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                Window ss = new Window();
                ss.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(ss_Loaded);
                ss.ShowDialog();
                (sender as Control).BringIntoView();        
            }   

private void ss_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as Window).Close();
        }
```

***Question:*** I know there must be something else going on, but I just can't identify it, but I really want to know what happened when a window showing with `ShowDialog`? Is this because it refreshes the `window` so that the `BringIntoView` will happen only after the `usercontrol` been loaded? (Not as the problem I have now: `BringIntoView` happened first, and then the `window` get refreshed and put the `scrollbar` back to the top). And what is the correct fix for my problem?

Comment: what else do you have in scrollviewer other than your usercontrol?

Comment: I've created setup as you described in throwaway project and it works as you expect it to without any window. You have to have something else going on in there that you think is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @nit, I have a `ContentControl`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `BringIntoView` called before my `Usercontrol` getting rendered, as a result when it gets fully rendered, the `scrollbar` is revert back to the top (as I have described in my question). And thanks for the answer from [@Evgeny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18569270/352101) posted for another question, I get a better solution now (less hack maybe?). Still want to see if there are better solutions.

```
   private void MyView_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
        var border = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        if (border.IsVisible)
        {
            //Window ss = new Window();
            //ss.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(ss_Loaded);
            //ss.ShowDialog();
            using (BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker())
            {
                bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_DoWork);
                bg.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bg_RunWorkerCompleted);
                Tuple<FrameworkElement, double> b = new Tuple<FrameworkElement, double>(border, border.Height);
                bg.RunWorkerAsync(b);
            }
        }
   }       

    private void bg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        (e.Result as UserControl).BringIntoView();
    }

    private void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {   
        int maxwait = 300 //not scrolled to the view is not a disaster, but if the program hangs forever it will be a disaster, so set this to prevent that from happening
        while (maxwait!=0 
               && 
               (e.Argument as Tuple<FrameworkElement, double>).Item1.ActualHeight != (e.Argument as Tuple<FrameworkElement, double>).Item2)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            maxwait --;
        }
        e.Result = (e.Argument as Tuple<FrameworkElement, double>).Item1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot believe that using background worker is a correct solution for this! You can use LayoutUpdated event to easily find when control is loaded and finally displayed.

```
userControl.LayoutUpdated+=OnLayoutUpdated;    
private bool loaded=false;


    private void OnLayoutUpdated(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
      if (!loaded && (view.ActualHeight > 0 || view.ActualWidth > 0))
      {
         // Unsubscribe or set a flag.
         userControl.LayoutUpdated -= OnLayoutUpdated;
         loaded = true;
      }
    }
```

So you can execute that code when layout is updated and height or width is set. This will means that control is loaded and displayed.
Than you can unsubscribe or set a flag that initialization is complated.